# how to expand only few nodes of a tree view in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

I am using a Treeview inside a Update Panel. On load of the treeview I want to expand the nodes only will 3 levels ie Depth =3. I used Expand Depth property and set "ExpandDepth=3".
But expand is not working. Appreciate your help.

Comment: private void ExpandAll()
    {

       foreach (TreeNode i in TreeView1.Nodes)
       {

           i.Expand();
              
           foreach (TreeNode f in i.ChildNodes)
           {

               f.Expand();

               foreach (TreeNode g in f.ChildNodes)
               {
                   if(g.Depth==0)
                   {
                   
                       g.Expand();
                   }
               }
               
               
           }
       }

    }

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed with the below code.

private void ExpandAll()
    {

```
   foreach (TreeNode i in TreeView1.Nodes)
   {

       i.Expand();

       foreach (TreeNode f in i.ChildNodes)
       {

           f.Expand();

           foreach (TreeNode g in f.ChildNodes)
           {
               if(g.Depth==0)
               {

                   g.Expand();
               }
           }


       }
   }

}
```